# Reorder SSIS Variables in Variables Window

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

Let's say I have the following variable names in the SSIS Variables window:

```
donut
apple
salad
```

I want to reorder them in the least painful way as possible to

```
apple
donut
salad
```

In other words, I want them alphabetical, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems all I had to do was click on the "Name" header.

I promise I searched Google before posting this, but hey, at least problem is solved?